# multiple lines made into 1 line of data

Tags: excel

I have attached a picture of what im trying to do.
I run these reports on my techs once a week. on the left side of the picture it shows the service order number multiple times and then the the booked date and closed date the techs id number actual hours work and then sold hours. the problem is it has many lines with the same service order. i need to make it look like the line to the right. 1 usable line of data so that i can process the reports the way i need to.

[image]

Comment: *I have attached a picture of what im trying to do*  A picture is worth a thousand words, but a thousand words is also worth a thousand words. What have you tried so far? Use your words to describe it and please include any code or formula attempt you have made.

Comment: Delete all the blank rows, and then just use a pivot table to get your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Copy A1:E32 all your Data without column F and paste it in I1 it will be I1:M32 for example, select I1:M32 the new Data under Data Tab click on Remove Duplicates you will have one row for each different entry
If the Number in Ro-no (column I) is unique for each entry, use the following in N2:
`=Sumif($A$2:$A$32,I2,$F$2:$F$32)`
and drag it down
It will sum the Sold Hours in column F for each RO-NO
Change the references to include all your rows and keep $

Answer (score 0):

### Power query

One of solutions is to use MS [power query](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379) addin. In Office 2016 and alike the PQ is built-in feature, located on the Data tab, Get and Transform group.

Let's say we have data like this:

[image]

We can use the Power query to Group By, like so:

[image]

The query will remember the steps you 'teach' it.

Comment: Thank you that is totally awesome!!

Comment: @MichaelClifford, you're welcome. Did it work? Problem solved?